# How to get limit data for each day

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I want to fetch some data during a particular time;
like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IS_ORIGINAL, IS_RELEASED, WORK_ID, IMG_URL, CREATE_TIME
    FROM TB_WORK WHERE USER_ID=#{userId}
    HAVING CREATE_TIME BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL #{startDays} DAY) AND CURDATE()
    ORDER BY CREATE_TIME
```

but I want to set a limit num for each day, like 20, how could I do that, thanks advanced.

Comment: add `limit 20` at the end

Comment: you need to add `limit 20` at the end of the query

Comment: really? I want to limit every day

Comment: what is your "num" ? And by day, do you mean real time or the system time ?

Comment: the given time, like from 2017/12/12 to 2017/12/20